# Use tmux for managing multiple downloaders as a supervisorctl service?

Tags: linux, bash, wget, supervisord, tmux

I have many data-servers I need to download data from via http as soon as it is available. For each server I start a `bash` "`while true`"-loop and within that a `wget` to poll the server for new data. To start all the `bash`s I created a `tmux` config starting a window for every loop such loop and `wget`. This adds the benefit of easier inspecting what is happening.

I want to create a `supervisor`-service from this config, which would allow me to start, stop, and restart this `tmux` and its downloading clients all at once.

However, when I quit `tmux`, by the very nature of `tmux`, the `bash`s and their `wget`s keep running. Is there a way around that, so I can quit everything and restart everything with a simple `supvervisorctl tmuxservice restart`?

Comment: `tmux` isn't what you really want, then, is it?

Comment: well, it would allow me to introspect, what the downloads are doing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say "quit `tmux`", I suppose you're really quitting just a *session*. 
If you kill a `tmux` session all the windows in it will be shut down.
For example if you started `tmux` with:

```
tmux new-session -s test1
```

Then you can shut it down with all its windows using:

```
tmux kill-session -t test1
```

You can create a supervisor service around your config and these commands.